# What is right way to design an component class with private properties in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there any recommended way to have private properties/Variables for the component and update the values in Constructor and use those properties throughout the components

Example:

```js
export default class Workarea extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    MenuProps = this.props.navigation.getParam('MenuProps', {})
  }
  
  MenuProps= {};
    
  getCurrentForm = () => {
    if(MenuProps.Type == "Type1") {
      this.RenderType1();
    }
    if(MenuProps.Type == "type2") {
      this.RenderType2();
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
       {
           this.getCurrentForm()
       }
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Is this the right way of doing class and property based approach.
Or i should always set the value and props to state please recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I ain't familiar with ReactNative, but es6 classes do not support private properties. The way to achieve them though, is to just declare the variable outside the class, but in the same file, like this:

```
    let _somePrivateProperty='hey';


     export default class Workarea extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       MenuProps = this.props.navigation.getParam('MenuProps', {})
      }

    MenuProps= {};

    getCurrentForm = () => {
      if(MenuProps.Type == "Type1") {
        this.RenderType1();
      }
      if(MenuProps.Type == "type2") {
        this.RenderType2();
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{_somePrivateProperty}</p>
          <View>
            {
             this.getCurrentForm()
            }
          </View>
        </div

      )
    }
  }
```

Hope that this is what you meant.

Comment: if i declare the private properties outside the calls, Is it possible to set the value in the constructor.?

Comment: I think so..Just try, and let me know :D. After all, this is just JS, React or not